# I'm not sure why my code is not stored XSS

Tags: php, html, mysql, xss

Update: I changed my payload to `"<img src="fake.jpg"  onerror="alert()">` and the XSS worked so I still don't know why the  won't work but at least my stored XSS is working right now.
Thanks for everyone helping.

I downloaded a code from GitHub that is a chat, the code is written in PHP and MYSQL I want to make that chat vulnerable to stored XSS, and I quite can't figure why it's not.
Of course, everything is stored inside the database but whenever I try to inject XSS the tags or the content of the tags aren't showing, but in the database, I see the alert() it's just not letting me see it on the website itself...
Does anyone know what might cause the problem?
Here's the index.php:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>::Message::</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function ajax() {
            var req =  new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                } 
            }
            req.open('GET','chat.php', true);
            req.send();
        }
        setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">

<div class="page">
    <div class="display-box">
        <div id="chat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
            <label for="message">Write some thing:</label><br>
            <textarea name="message" id="message-write" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_chat (name, message) VALUES ('$name','$message')";
            $run = $con->query($query);
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the chat:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_chat` ORDER BY id DESC";
            $run = $con->query($query);
            while($row = $run->fetch_array()):
        ?>
        <div class="chating_data">
            <span id="name"><?php echo $row['name'];?></span><br>
            <span id="message"><?php echo $row['message'];?></span>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Your code is SQL injection vulnerable, it crash when you try to send `'`, etc... There is no problem with XSS only.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
But whenever im trying to inject XSS im only doing <script>alert()</script> without quotes. 
Is it a problem even though I'm not using quotes?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to both SQL injection and XSS. What do you see in the browser when you view the generated page?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the response, I've managed to fix it thanks to the comment below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the markup generated properly, as you expect it?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yea everything is working properly, as I wrote the payload is stored in the database and I can see it there, it just doesn't show on the page for some reason.
Anyway, another payload worked.
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be using a modern browser that prevents the exploit for you. That does not mean the application is not vulnerable, it only means it is so straightforwardly vulnerable that even the browser can detect an exploit automatically.

Try sending the following response header:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

You can do so with something like `header('X-XSS-Protection: 0');` and see if that allows you to try XSS. Also you can display XSS messages in this chat not in a response to your "malicious" request but afterwards - it should then work because the browser will have no way to associate your request with the response.

Comment: Hey, this seem to not be the problem because whenever i use a payload like "<img src="fakeimage.jpg" onerror="alert()"> it works. I did manage to store the XSS in the database but <script>alert()</script> just doesn't work.
Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That kind of further supports my guess, img works because that's not stopped by the built-in browser protection, while script is prevented.

Comment: It didn't fix the script tags even after I added the header "X-XSS-Protection: 0
" ... 
But anyway I accepted the answer because my problem is fixed.
Thanks again!